# The correct way of passing an array into a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters

I am relatively new to C and can't figure out what is wrong with the code?

I am getting 2 warnings during compile time and Segmentation fault core dump error during run time. Can anyone explain why? I am running Ubuntu as a virtual machine. And is this the correct way to declare/pass an array into a function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Loop handlers 
int i, j, m, n;
int c;
int cap[26];


//Funtions prototype
void countingChars(void);
void vertcalHistogram(int [], int size);    //Warning: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’ (helloworld)
void dashes(void);

int main (void)
{
    countingChars();
    vertcalHistogram( cap[26], 26); //Warning: passing argument 1 of ‘vertcalHistogram’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] (helloworld)
    //dashes();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void countingChars(void)
{
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c >= 65 && c <= 90)
            ++cap[c - 65];

        if(c >= 97 && c <= 122)
            ++cap[c - 97];

        for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            printf("%d", cap[i]);
        printf("\n");

    }   
}
void dashes(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        printf("_");

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        printf("_");

}

void vertcalHistogram(int cap[], int size)
{
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        printf("||");
        for(j = 0; j < cap[i]; j++)
            printf("*");
        printf(" ~~ %d", cap[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all stop using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Then learn about [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and [other related functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: If you're getting compilation warnings, you should show those (preferably as the compiler generates them).  You should use local variables, not globals, for at least `i`, `j`, `m`, `n` and `c` — I've not scrutinized `cap`.  Single letter global variables are almost inevitably bogus.  A global variable should have a meaningful name (it is used many places) and you can't manage that in a single letter.

Comment: `vertcalHistogram( cap[26], 26);` — you're passing an out of bounds element of the array as the array.  Wrong.  You need `vertcalHistogram(cap, 26);`.  That accounts for the compilation warnings and the core dump.  Passing an arbitrary, undefined (but possibly zero) integer as a pointer is going to lead to crashes.  Heed the compiler; fix the warnings before running the code.

Answer (score 2):

`cap[26]` is the 27th element of `cap`, and since `cap[]` is an array of `int`, the 27th element is of type `int`.  You need to pass `cap`, not `cap[26]`.

---

<sup>Also, you would do yourself a great favour to enable the "treat all warnings as errors" option of your compiler, so as to not even try running your program if you get warnings.</sup>

<sup>Also, try this: `#define COUNTOF(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))` so then you can call your function like this: `vertcalHistogram( cap, COUNTOF(cap) );`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to pass the address of array itself or the address of the first element:

```
vertcalHistogram( cap, 26);
```

or

```
vertcalHistogram( &cap[0], 26);
```

But it doesn't seem to be necessary since `cap` is a global variable in your code.

`cap[26]` is outside the bounds of the array. Remember C indexing starts from 0. So for an array of size 26, `0` to `25` is the valid index range.

Comment: It's better to avoid globals; the `vertcalHistogram()` function could be used more generally because it takes the array as an argument rather than relying on the global.  It's the rest of the code that should be de-global-ized.

Answer (score 1):

`cap[26]` means the `int` at index `26` in the `cap` array.

If you want to pass `cap`, write `cap`:

```
verticalHistogram(cap, 26);
```

Answer (score 0):

`cap[26]` is 1 element passed the last element of `char` array `cap[]`.  Original code is passing a `char` and not an array.  Certainly not what is intended.

```
void vertcalHistogram(int [], int size); 
int cap[26];
...
vertcalHistogram( cap[26], 26);  // bad
...
void vertcalHistogram(int cap2[], int size)  // Changed name for clarity
```

> In C, arrays are not truly passed to functions.

Detail: Instead use the following.  The array `cap` is a *formal parameter* to `vertcalHistogram()`.  C does not pass arrays, instead it converts the array to the address and type of the first element.  This actual parameter is passed to the function.  The function receives the address as `cap2[]`.

```
vertcalHistogram( cap, 26);  // good
```